# Evaluation order in python list and tuple literals

Tags: python

Let's say we have something like this:

```
a = (fcn1(), fcn2())
b = [fcn1(), fcn2()]
```

Does the Python interpreter evaluate `fcn1()` before `fcn2()`, or is the order undefined?

Comment: If you're really worried about it, you could use:  `a = tuple(x() for x in (fcn1,fcn2))` or a corresponding list comprehension ... Though I'm pretty sure the functions will be evaluated left to right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are evaluated from [left to right](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order).

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)(for lists):

> When a comma-separated list of expressions is supplied, its elements
>   are evaluated from left to right and placed into the list object in
>   that order.

Small test using `dis.dis()`:

```
In [208]: def f1():pass

In [209]: def f2():pass

In [210]: import dis

In [212]: def func():

        a = (f1(), f2())
        b  = [f1(), f2()]
       .....:     

In [213]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f1)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (f2)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             15 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f1)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             24 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (f2)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             30 BUILD_LIST               2
             33 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note: In case of assignment, the right hand side is evaluated first.

Comment: That is true of the standard Python interpreter. But is it *required* to be true?

Comment: @chepner I believe yes : http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays

Comment: The dis module looks cool! didn't know python has such a tool.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

expressions are evaluated [left to right](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). This link specifically treats the `tuple` case.  Here's another [link](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) which specifically treats the list case.