# Why does this Python script does not execute in order?

Tags: python

I've got the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def bad_f1():
    print 'foo'
    return

def bad_f2():
    print 'bar'
    return

def bad_my_function(a, list_f, b):
    print a
    for i in list_f:
        i
    print b
    return

bad_my_function('a', [bad_f1(), bad_f2()], 'b')
```

As I call my script, I would expect the result to be :

```
a
foo
bar
b
```

But I got :

```
foo
bar
a
b
```

Even though I call `print a` first in my function, it is executed after.

On a side not :

```
def f1():
    return 'foo'

def f2():
    return 'bar'

def my_function(a, list_f, b):
    print a
    for i in list_f:
        print i
    print b
    return

my_function('a', [f1(), f2()], 'b')
```

`my_function(...)` give the expected result.

Why does `bad_my_function(...)` behave in this strange way? Is it the way I call functions in a list? Does it have to do with the way I print `'foo'` and `'bar'`?

Comment: Did you mean `my_function('a', [f1, f2], 'b')` in the last line and `i()` in the for loop?

Comment: Have you tried both versions [on Pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to see the differences in execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code cannot call `bad_my_function` until it has all of the arguments to pass to it. It gets one of those arguments by calling `bad_f1()` and `bad_f2()`, so those calls have to happen first.

Simpler example:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    print("foo")

def bar():
    print("bar")
    return 2

foo(1, bar(), 3)
```

This will output "bar" before "foo".  How could it be otherwise? Exactly what do you expect to be passed into `foo` as the value of its `b` parameter if `bar` has not been called yet?

Comment: It was simpler than I though! The loop lead me to think the problem was there... The question might be a duplicate then...

Answer (score 3):

of course since to evaluate the arguments of

```
my_function('a', [bad_f1(), bad_f2()], 'b')
```

python needs to call `bad_f1` and `bad_f2` first, which `print`. so that's expected.

Also note that there could be an ambiguity in `bad_f1` and `bad_f2` order too. Well, there isn't since list arguments are evaluated from left to right ([Evaluation order in python list and tuple literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487350/evaluation-order-in-python-list-and-tuple-literals))

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is written, `bad_my_function()` can't execute until after `bad_f1()` and `bad_f2()` have been called in its argument list. `bad_f1()` and `bad_f2()` print `foo` and `bar` respectively, so those two actions will occur first.

Once that has happened, `bad_my_function()` can execute, which results in `a` and `b` being printed.

The reason your second block of code works as expected is because it executes in the same order as your first block, but it only returns the `foo` and `bar` values, rather than printing them -- which is done inside `my_function()`, after `print a` and before `print b`.